# Button Edge getting clipped

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

Here's my XML code for an interface for an app :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".PNRActivity" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pnr_num"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:hint="@string/pnr_number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="50dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_pnr"
                android:text="@string/btnGetStatus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/centerPoint"
                android:layout_width="5dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_pnr"
                android:text="@string/btnClear" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:text="@string/btnClear"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

It works as intended for most devices however in few devices the button gets clipped viz.

Well II must mention it was a physical device (Galaxy S II) running gingerbread. Is it a problem with my code? I can't emulate 2.2.3 as my target is set to 4.*. Is there a way to change that?

[image]

Comment: reduce `paddingTop` of your `LinearLayout` that holds buttons and textview

Comment: will that be all? say reducing 5dip?

Comment: you can try doing that and see what happens